# How to add comma in PHP result table

Tags: php

How to add the comma in the search result table using PHP? Below is the code that I get. The result sticks together without the comma in the second column, and I try to add the comma such as `echo $aaa =  $newlist->name.',';`. It didn't work.

[image: table]

```
<tr>
    <th>Class Name </th>
    <th>Class Type</th>
    <th>Recommended Fitness Level</th>
    <th>Location</th>
</tr>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < $countposts; $i++) {

    $pid = $unique_posts[$i];
    $title = get_the_title($pid);
    $location = get_field('location', $pid);
    $fitness_level = get_field('fitness_level', $pid);
    $imp_fitness = implode(',', $fitness_level);
    include("locationfile.php");
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
        <td><?php
            $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($pid, 'classtypecategory', array("fields" => "all"));
            foreach ($term_list as $newlist) {
                echo $aaa = $newlist->name . '';
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $imp_fitness; ?></td>                   
        <td><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $location; ?></a></td>
    </tr>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: The image is so poor in quality that I can't see the result. Is it text? Why not copy paste it here instead?

Comment: The code in text and the code in code is not the same. `echo $aaa   =  $newlist->name.'';` no comma there

Comment: Use the PHP concatenation assignment operator (.=) to append a string with another string.

Comment: Yup, Andreas so i try add comma like $aaa =  $newlist->name.','; but the result also stick together

Answer (score -1):

```
//Method 1:
foreach($term_list as $newlist){
$aaa   .=  $newlist->name.','; 
} 
echo $aaa=substr($aaa,0,-1);

//Method 2:
// For implode
foreach($term_list as $newlist){
$text[] =  $newlist->name; 
} 
echo $aaa=implode(',',$text);
```

try this,instead of your foreach

Comment: Implode is a better option

Comment: Thanks to reply, but it still stick  together. Image link: https://imgur.com/a/hBuBoG4

Comment: Yes, but you might as well type it with a pen and paper then scan it with an OCR reader. That will work too. But it's not a good solution just because you can.